# Ignoring version changes during merges

Tags: git, maven, version-control

## Exposition

This is a situation I run into a lot. The first thing our team does in release branches is drop the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix from the version. We make any last minute changes as necessary, sometimes this includes making bigfixes. I've made a same git log below showing this. (At the end of the question a more detailed log is shown incase it helps explain better.)

```
* ea88c23 (release/1.0.0) Fix an embarrasing bug
* 5fe35e1 Drop SNAPSHOT in prep for release
| * 34433c6 (HEAD -> master) Add important features
| * fe41d3b Bump version to 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
|/
* 8dcfc4f Add greet feature
* 0337c4c Bump version to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
* 775277d Inital commit
```

Essentially what happens is

1. Project is going along
2. A release branch is cut
3. In parallel...

   - Version changed on the release branch
   - Version changed on the active development branch
4. Parallel continued...

   - A bug is fixed on the release branch
   - A feature is added on the active development branch

## Question

Now, how do I get those changes from the release branch (`release/1.0.0`) branch back into the active development branch (`master`) ***cleanly?*** I have a couple of potential solutions below, none are terribly favorable.

### Naive approach

```
git checkout master
git merge release/1.0.0
# Fix conflicts manually
```

Bear in mind that this example is simplified down to a small number of commits and the version is only located in a single file, but in reality there could be many changes and many files with the version; because of this the naive approach of just merging `release/1.0.0` into `master` and fixing the conflicts due to the versions changing is a lot more difficult and annoying.

### Slightly less naive approach

```
git checkout master
git merge release/1.0.0
git checkout --ours */pom.xml
```

If all that is changing in the POM files is the version then it's fine, but this is dangerous because there could be other changes in the pom files other than versions. Of course you can do `git diff` before `git checkout --ours */pom.xml` to be safe, but this is still annoying.

### Cherry-picking

I don't fully understand how to cherry-pick, but I understand what it does. A pro of this approach would be that it's easy to ignore the one commit that you always don't want, but a con is that you end up with a lot of extra commits, which isn't necessarily bad but seems bad.

Maybe this is the best approach and I am just nervous for nothing. It just seems like there'd be times where you find a problem with a single commit (for whatever reason) and hunt down where it is affecting things but if it was cherry-picked (or from a cherry-pick) then you could miss some spots.

---

#### Fuller log

```
* ea88c23 (release/1.0.0) Fix an embarrasing bug
| diff --git a/file b/file
| index e98206a..8ab686e 100644
| --- a/file
| +++ b/file
| @@ -1 +1 @@
| -Hell, World!
| +Hello, World!
* 5fe35e1 Drop SNAPSHOT in prep for release
| diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
| index f755149..3eefcb9 100644
| --- a/pom.xml
| +++ b/pom.xml
| @@ -1 +1 @@
| -1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
| +1.0.0
| * 34433c6 (HEAD -> master) Add important features
| | diff --git a/file2 b/file2
| | new file mode 100644
| | index 0000000..e6afbe7
| | --- /dev/null
| | +++ b/file2
| | @@ -0,0 +1 @@
| | +Import features
| * fe41d3b Bump version to 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
|/
|   diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
|   index f755149..5902d52 100644
|   --- a/pom.xml
|   +++ b/pom.xml
|   @@ -1 +1 @@
|   -1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
|   +1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
* 8dcfc4f Add greet feature
| diff --git a/file b/file
| new file mode 100644
| index 0000000..e98206a
| --- /dev/null
| +++ b/file
| @@ -0,0 +1 @@
| +Hell, World!
* 0337c4c Bump version to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
| diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
| new file mode 100644
| index 0000000..f755149
| --- /dev/null
| +++ b/pom.xml
| @@ -0,0 +1 @@
| +1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
* 775277d Inital commit
  diff --git a/.gitattributes b/.gitattributes
  new file mode 100644
  index 0000000..176a458
  --- /dev/null
  +++ b/.gitattributes
  @@ -0,0 +1 @@
  +* text=auto
  diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
  new file mode 100644
  index 0000000..e69de29
```

Comment: You can avoid this problem entirely by deriving the version automatically from a Git tag, rather than hardcoding it (and thus having to commit it).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Not every commit is tagged, maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean though.

Comment: You tag the first commit on the branch as something like "1.1.0-rc", and then tag the final commit as "1.1.0".  You then derive the version from `git describe`, which is typically handled by a plugin (at least in Gradle, not sure what's on offer in the Maven ecosystem).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth What gradle plugin does this? That may be worth looking into.

Comment: e.g. https://github.com/palantir/gradle-git-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this happens a lot, I found a solution to this while writing my question.

From the log snippet `5fe35e1` is the commit we *don't* want in `master`, it's the one that will cause us problems.

> ```
> * ea88c23 (release/1.0.0) Fix an embarrasing bug
> * 5fe35e1 Drop SNAPSHOT in prep for release
> | * 34433c6 (HEAD -> master) Add important features
> | * fe41d3b Bump version to 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
> |/
> * 8dcfc4f Add greet feature
> * 0337c4c Bump version to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
> * 775277d Inital commit
> ```

Let's just get rid of it!

```
git checkout release/1.0.0
git checkout -b port-to-1.1.0
git revert 5fe35e1
# Now port-to-1.1.0 has all the changes we want and none of the ones we don't
git checkout master
git merge port-to-1.1.0
```

You may still have conflicts but you won't have any from bumping the version. This approach can be used to "get rid of" any commits you don't want. Your log will now be like below. Remember, reverting doesn't delete the commit itself, it simply undoes all the changes that single commit introduced. You can see below that `5fe35e1` is still there.

```
*   6683b44 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'port-to-1.1.0'
|\
| * 81e9bf5 (port-to-1.1.0) Revert "Drop SNAPSHOT in prep for release"
| * ea88c23 (release/1.0.0) Fix an embarrasing bug
| * 5fe35e1 Drop SNAPSHOT in prep for release
* | 34433c6 Add important features
* | fe41d3b Bump version to 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
|/
* 8dcfc4f Add greet feature
* 0337c4c Bump version to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
* 775277d Inital commit
```